# JavaScript: Create a function that creates and returns a function; function not defined error

Tags: javascript, function, return, higher-order-functions

My objective is:

Create a function createFunction that creates and returns a function. When that newly created function is called, it should return the string 'hello world'.

I tried the code below:

```
function createFunction(){

  return function printHelloWorld(){

    return 'hello world'; 

  }
  return printHelloWorld; 
}

const myFunction = createFunction();
console.log(myFunction());
```

Any thoughts on why I am not passing the second test? 
[image]

Comment: You have two `return` statements in `createFunction`, the second one is dead code.

Comment: @Bergi, except for that, the code runs just fine. OP, could create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible? This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: My only thoughts are either A) This code isn't at global scope, but the checker expects it to be at global scope, or B) This code is at global scope, but the checker expects to find `myFunction` on the global object, which it won't because `const` (even at global scope) doesn't put a property on the global object. (That second would be a failure of the checker. Well, both of them would be, really...) That code definitely creates an in-scope `myFunction` that, when called, returns the relevant string.

Comment: Where are you getting those error messages from? What do the checks exactly test? And is that the exact code you tried? ("*myFunction should create and return a function*" sounds dubious, shouldn't `createFunction` do that?)

Comment: ^^ what Bergi said. The first two statements in that list conflict with each other. Should `myFunction` return a function, or return the string `"hello world"`?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
function createFunction(){

  return function(){

    return 'hello world'; 

  }
}

const myFunction = createFunction();
console.log(myFunction());
```